# Sybase ASE: How to disable non-standard group by extensions

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sap-ase

Sybase ASE has a functional extension compared to ANSI standard **group by** where it can accept in select fields that don’t make part of **group by**. The end result is some kind of self-join and even the documentation says it is a very confusing feature.

**Example:**

```
create table #a(id numeric(9), client varchar(50), city  varchar(50))
insert #a values (1, 'aaa','New York')
insert #a values (2, 'aaa','New Jersey')
insert #a values (3, 'bbb','New York')
insert #a values (4, 'ccc','New Jersey')
insert #a values (5, 'aaa','Atlanta')

select count(*),city from #a group by city
select count(*),city,client from #a group by city,client
select count(*),city,client from #a group by city
```

**Results:**

```
--      |city       |
--    --|-----------|
--    2 |New York   |
--    1 |Atlanta    |
--    2 |New Jersey |
--    
--      |city       |client |
--    --|-----------|-------|
--    1 |New Jersey |ccc    |
--    1 |New Jersey |aaa    |
--    1 |New York   |bbb    |
--    1 |Atlanta    |aaa    |
--    1 |New York   |aaa    |
--    
--    
--    select count(*),city,client from #a group by city
--      |city       |client |
--    --|-----------|-------|
--    2 |New York   |aaa    |
--    2 |New York   |bbb    |
--    1 |Atlanta    |aaa    |
--    2 |New Jersey |aaa    |
--    2 |New Jersey |ccc    |
```

While first two queries are standard, the last one will fail on most of the databases, except SYBASE ASE.

In the query: 
select count(*),city,**client** from #a group by city  , **city** is not part of **group by**

The results are confusing, and it is very easy to make a mistake by adding an extra field to the select clause. In this case not only the results are confusing, but the query can force full table scans and on big tables that could lead to long times until the issue becomes apparent.

Is there a way using a client/connection configuration (or something else) to disable this functionality?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: The third one used to work in MySQL until version 5.7.5. Fortunately that "feature" is now disabled by default in newer versions of MySQL.

Comment: As it is, the third query is not SQL compliant. On the other hand, if `city` were a key of the table (primary or other), then it would be a valid SQL query, since `client` would be fully dependent on `city` (according to the SQL Standard)... but it's not the case.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yeah, I wan't to remove this "feature" from mu connections. Btw, if the city was a key ... Do you mean standard SQL valid query or just on some engines?

Comment: fwiw, `set fipsflagger on` will cause a **warning** message to be generated for non-ANSI standard commands/clauses, but this won't disable the command/query in question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I forgot to add the explicit question. Added